# Vector C++. Ввод вектора с клавиатуры

Tags: c++, vector

Есть код:

```
int g[500][500], n;
cin >> n;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
       cin >> g[i][j];
```

Как мне заменить статический массив вектором?

Т.е. `vector <vector <int>> g(n);`

**Как осуществить ввод данных из клавиатуры в вектор (двумерный)?**

*P.S.Это для графов.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вместо `int g[500][500]` -

```
vector<vector<int>> g(500,vector<int>(500));
```

Но лучше так:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<vector<int>> g(n,vector<int>(n));

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cin >> n;
vector <vector <int>> g(n, vector<int>(n));
```

А дальше без изменений.

Answer (score 0):

// А просто так, например:

vector < int > g;

int i, j, n, x;

cin >> n;

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
    cin >> x;
    g.push_back(x);
    }
}
```